# Twisted DeferredList only runs its callback half the time

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing, twisted

I'm trying to make a fairly simple web scraper using Twisted. I have it working, but whenever I try to scrape more than a few hundred sites, it will hang indefinitely for no discernible reason. Everything seems to work, except when it stops at the very end with a couple sites left to process.

I used the tutorial here: http://technicae.cogitat.io/2008/06/async-batching-with-twisted-walkthrough.html as a blueprint.

Here is my code:

```
class Spider:
    """Twisted-based html retrieval system."""

    def __init__(self, queue, url_list):
        self.process_queue = queue
        self.start_urls = []
        for url in url_list:
            self.start_urls.append(url)

    def crawl(self):
        """Extracts information from each website in start_urls."""
        deferreds = []
        sem = defer.DeferredSemaphore(30)
        for url in self.start_urls:
            d = sem.run(self._crawl, url, self.process_queue)
            deferreds.append(d)
        dl = defer.DeferredList(deferreds, consumeErrors=1)
        dl.addCallback(self.finish, self.process_queue)
        dl.addCallback(self.shutdown)
        reactor.run()

    def _crawl(self, url, queue):
        d = getPage(url, timeout=10)
        d.addCallback(self.parse, url, queue)
        d.addErrback(self.parse_error, url, queue)
        return d

    def parse(self, result, url, queue):
        print 'Parsing:', url
        data = {'body': result, 'url': url}
        response = Response(data['url'], data['body'])
        queue.put(response)
        return data

    def parse_error(self, result, url, queue):
        print 'Errback from:', url
        data = {'body': 'error', 'url': url}
        response = Response(data['url'], data['body'])
        queue.put(response)
        return data

    def finish(self, results, queue):
        for (valid, data) in results:
            if valid:
                print 'Success:', data['url']
            else:
                print 'Failed:', data['url']
        finish_signal = Response('FINISHED', 'DONE')
        queue.put(finish_signal)

    def shutdown(self, ignore):
        reactor.stop()
```

I am running this section of code in a larger program, hence the Queue.

Any suggestions for making the DeferredList always fire? Or ideas as to why it's only firing half the time, and failing without any exceptions the other half?

It's very frustrating, especially since it works perfectly with small numbers of URL's (1-100) but fails when scaled up. I am new to Twisted, so I probably just messed up something with the errbacks, but I can't figure out what, or how to fix it...

Also, before anyone answers with 'use Scrapy!' I can't use Scrapy for reasons I won't get into here. Assume this program is my last hope and must work.

EDIT:

Full standalone code so people can run it directly:

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.web.client import getPage

class SeerSpider:
    """Twisted-based html retrieval system."""

    def __init__(self, queue, url_list):
        self.process_queue = queue
        self.start_urls = []
        for url in url_list:
            self.start_urls.append(url)

    def crawl(self):
        """Extracts information from each website in url_list."""
        deferreds = []
        sem = defer.DeferredSemaphore(30)
        for url in self.start_urls:
            d = sem.run(self._crawl, url, self.process_queue)
            deferreds.append(d)
        dl = defer.DeferredList(deferreds, consumeErrors=True)
        dl.addCallback(self.finish, self.process_queue)
        dl.addCallback(self.shutdown)
        reactor.run()

    def _crawl(self, url, queue):
        d = getPage(url, timeout=10)
        d.addCallback(self.parse, url, queue)
        d.addErrback(self.parse_error, url, queue)
        return d

    def parse(self, result, url, queue):
        data = {'body': result, 'url': url}
        response = Response(data['url'], data['body'])
        print response.url
        return data

    def parse_error(self, result, url, queue):
        data = {'body': 'error','url': url}
        response = Response(data['url'], data['body'])
        print response.url
        return data

    def finish(self, results, queue):
        finish_signal = Response('FINISHED', 'DONE')
        print finish_signal.url

    def shutdown(self, ignore):
        reactor.stop()

class Response:
    def __init__(self, url, text):
        self.url = url
        self.body = text

url_list = ['http://google.com/', 'http://example.com', 'http://facebook.com'] # this will work, make the list bigger to find the bug
spider = SeerSpider(None, url_list)
spider.crawl()
```

Comment: Take a look at [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It's built on Twisted and is arguably one of the best crawling frameworks.

Comment: I said in my post I can't use Scrapy. This program has to be compileable to an exe, and I can't compile anything with Scrapy because of its weird custom importing modules.

Comment: I've never had problems with py2exe and Scrapy. What isn't working for you?

Comment: This program isn't complete.  There is no logic that kicks off the reactor, so nothing ever happens.  There are a number of bizarre choices you've made here - what is that `time.sleep` doing there, for example? - but I can't be sure that they're wrong unless I can actually run the thing and reproduce the problem that you're describing.

Comment: It's not complete because it's part of a larger program. The time.sleep was there for debugging, I thought maybe it was a problem with the sentinel object, so I wanted to make sure it entered after everything had finished processing. It doesn't need to be there, and I was planning on removing it after I figured out what was going wrong.

I'll edit my question to be more clear about what is happening elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing the standard library's multiprocessing library with use of Twisted.  If you're not very careful with this, random things will break.  For example, perhaps the reactor is satisfying some of the I/O events in one process and the rest in another process.

It's hard to say for *sure* this is the problem, though, since the sample code in the question is incomplete (you might think the rest of the program is boring, but all of those boring details taken together are what define the behavior of the program, so they're actually very important to your question).

Comment: It's not that I think it's boring, I just don't think it's relevant. I can replicate the error even when running a completely standalone version of the code, without any multiprocessing. 

Ignore all the queue's, comment them out and run the program with print statements. It does exactly the same thing with large lists of URL's. I just ran it with 563, and it processed 562 sites and is now hanging here doing nothing. No multiprocessing, no queue's, just printing out each URL as it is processed by the callbacks.

Comment: That's great.  It should be simpler to debug a problem with the completely standalone version of the code.  Can you post that?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll edit my post with a standalone version that can be run directly.

Comment: Alas, I tried with 3000+ URLs and didn't observe the problem you described. :/  I tried this on Debian Stable, Python 2.6.6, Twisted 10.1.0 and trunk@HEAD.

Comment: Thanks for trying! At least now I know it isn't a problem with the code itself, but rather some other environmental factor.

Comment: @oiez: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm encountering a simliar issue where almost all the deferreds complete, but a couple just hang and everything just waits.